# Как сделать пользовательский атрибут C#

Tags: c#, атрибуты

Хочу научиться работать с атрибутами, но не могу понять как правильно их написать. Сейчас пытаюсь сделать атрибут который будет задавать максимальное и минимальное значение для свойства типа `int` (типа как `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute`).

Как мне получить свойство, которое использует данный атрибут в моем классе `RangeAttribute` и сравнить значение свойства с полями?

```
[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
sealed class RangeAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    private int _minimum;
    private int _maximum;
        
    public RangeAttribute(int minimum, int maximum)
    {
        _minimum = minimum;
        _maximum = maximum;
    }
    public override bool Match(object obj)
    {
        //Что тут писать? Или может мне этот метод вообще не нужен?
    }
}
```

Использовать буду так:

```
class Test
{
    [Range(1, 10)]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, вы немного не так понимаете атрибуты. Они не делают магические проверки за вас, не вызываются автоматически. Это, по сути, простой класс, который указывается в свойствах другого класса/метода/свойства, элемент рефлексии. Если дописать ваш код, то вы можете, к примеру в классе `Test` создать метод, который будет проверять атрибут, а дальше его вызывать там, где надо, нечто такое: `bool CheckValue() => typeof(Test).GetProperty(nameof(Value)).GetCustomAttribute<RangeAttribute>().Min < Value;`, где `Min < Value` - некая логика (можно сделать метод в атрибуте и вызывать его).

Comment: Касательно `public override bool Match(object obj)` - это не то, о чем вы подумали. Это некий механизм, при помощи которого вы можете сверить два атрибута на идентичность. [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.attribute.match).

Comment: Вот [RangeAttribute.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/RangeAttribute.cs), изучайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если делать так, как именно хотите вы:

```
[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
sealed class RangeAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    private int _minimum;
    private int _maximum;

    public RangeAttribute(int minimum, int maximum)
    {
        _minimum = minimum;
        _maximum = maximum;
    }
    public bool InRange(int value) => value >= _minimum && value <= _maximum;
}

class Test
{
    private int _value;
    [RangeAttribute(1, 10)]
    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set => _value = this
            .GetType()
            .GetProperty(nameof(Value))
            .GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .Cast<RangeAttribute>()
            .Single()
            .InRange(value) ? value : _value;
    }
}
```

Проверяем:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.Value //0 логично, _value по-умолчанию 0
test.Value = 1;
test.Value //1 успешно записалось
test.Value = 15;
test.Value //1 успешно соблюдает диапазон и не даёт записать 15
test.Value = 5;
test.Value //5 дал записать 5
```

Главное учитывайте, что на атрибуты, как и вообще на рефлексию с кучей вызовов методов - идут дополнительные вычислительные расходы.
PS цепочки вызовов в set'тере не избежать, можно конечно уменьшить, засунув под ковёр в отдельный класс, но магии не случится и атрибут сам не вызовется.
Данный подход нужен только на мой взгляд не более чём в 3 случаях:

- Самообучение с экспериментами
- Разработка библиотек/фреймворков
- Тырпрайз со своими стандартами

Если применение редко и разово, то лучше отказаться от атрибутов и сделать проще, а где нужно - ссылаться на внешний IsValidValue:

```
class Test
{
    private int _value;
    private const int _min_val = 1;
    private const int _max_val = 10;
    private bool IsValidValue(int value) => value >= _min_val && value <= _max_val;
    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set => _value = IsValidValue(value) ? value : _value;
    }
}
```

Можно сделать альтернативу любыми вариантами, создать поле для класса, который будет валидировать, делегат или прямо функцию/предикат проверки записывать в экземпляр класса Test.